# In Microsoft Azure, How to retrieve operationid (of applicationInsights) in api policy

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-api-management

In Azure API Inbound policy, how to retrieve application insights operationId field.

Tried with following in inbound xml but it did not work. also tried by `context.Variables["InvocationId"]`.

```
@{
 return (context.Operation.Id);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure APIM provides access to context via "context" variable. Documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions#ContextVariables. In general it gives you access to full HTTP request/response that, and in addition to whatever scope information APIM maintains itself, like API, operation, product e.t.c. You should be able to get value used for operationId as context.RequestId.