# How to get Operation ID (from App Insights end-to-end) in APIM Policies?

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-api-management

In Azure API Management Policies, how can I retrieve the OperationID field from Application Insights?

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51767671/in-microsoft-azure-how-to-retrieve-operationid-of-applicationinsights-in-api)

It seems that I can retrieve the OperationID using *context.RequestId*.

```
<set-body>@{
        var operationId = context.RequestId.ToString();
        return "OperationId: " + operationId;
        }</set-body>
```

But when I do that I'm getting a different ID than expected.

So for example, when I test it with Postman I receive the following Operation ID:
[image]

But when I look at the App Insight Logs, I see the following Operation ID:

[image]

Does anyone know how can I get the correct Operation ID from end-to-end transaction Application Insights?

Answer (score -1):

In your code you are using `RequestId`. In the `RequestId` you will get the **RequestId: Guid - unique request identifier**

For that you have to use the [context.Operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions#ref-context-operation) to get the Operation ID by using `context.Operation.Id`

```
<set-body>@{
        var operationId = context.Operation.Id.ToString();
        return "OperationId: " + operationId;
        }</set-body>
```

Comment: I tried that but it gives me the ID name of the API Operation, not the Operation ID of the App Insights.

Comment: operation id is the id of the operation on the api, not the id of the request calling the api